# How to show a button when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How to show a button whenever the checked a box is checked?

Tried to hide the button but i don't know how to show it when I checked at least one box.

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" 
hidden="hidden"
title="Save" 
v-on:click="save">
<span >Submit ({{pr.selected.length}}) </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a computed property

```
computed: {
   showButton() {
     if (this.p.item.selected) {
        return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

And to your button

```
<button v-if="showButton"/>
```

or

```
<button :class="{'is-hidden-class': !showButton}"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please develop your answer and explain why to add computed and what does it do. As you may have some readers that could come in years to read this answer, they would need to understand why to do it and what does it do.Never stop helping !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value of the button visibility in your state

```
data() {
  return {
     visible: true
  }
}
```

And then, rely your button on that state

```
<button v-if="visible">
```

and simply toggle the state

```
 // to show 
 this.visible = true;

 // to hide
 this.visible = false;
```